# Input as integer hours, output as positive or negative hh:mm format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a a really stupid question in regards to `string` output when given an `integer` input.

The stub of this method would look like this:

```
public string myMethod(int hours)
{
    return in -/+hours:mm format
}
```

Say we have an integer input `hours` as `1`, the output of this method would be `+01:00`.

Say we have an input of `-2`, the output of this method would be `-02:00`.

Say we have an input of `12`, the output of this method would be `+12:00`.

It appears in C#, there are ways to craft integer/double outputs so they appear a certain way via the use of `{}`.

How do I, using this integer formatter, to parse in an input of integers, and output in that particular format?

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
public string myMethod(int hours)
{
    return string.Format("{0:+#;-#}:00", hours);
}

Console.WriteLine(myMethod(1));   // +1:00
Console.WriteLine(myMethod(-2));  // -2:00
Console.WriteLine(myMethod(12));  // +12:00
```

Depending on precisely how you want to handle 0, you can use this:

```
public string myMethod(int hours)
{
    return string.Format("{0:+#;-#;+0}:00", hours);
}

Console.WriteLine(myMethod(0));   // +0:00
```

**Further Reading**

- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this method as I could use both hours and minutes:

```
public static string toTimeSpan(int hours, int minutes)
{
    if (hours < 0)
    {
        return "-" + TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).ToString(@"hh") + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).ToString(@"\:mm");
    }
    else
    {
        return "+" + TimeSpan.FromHours(hours).ToString(@"hh") + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).ToString(@"\:mm");
    }
}
```

Please let me know if it's incorrect. So far, it works for me pretty well.